# With Jersey, can I collect Param Conversion (data binding) and Validation errors into a single response?

Tags: java, error-handling, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Jersey seems to have 3 phases to process input from the request into method parameters for the methods handling the request, and errors can happen at all 3:

1. Unmarshalling - Going from a String into JSON or XML, for example
2. Data Binding - Going from a String or JSON into domain objects (PoJos)
3. Validation - Checking that the bound domain objects are valid

For Unmarshalling and Data Binding errors, Jersey seems to throw an Exception at the first problem and halt request processing, but with the Bean Validation API, it looks like all of the validation errors are collected and then wrapped into a single exception.

Instead, we want to be able to collect all of the Data Binding errors as well and bundle those in with the Validation errors so that we can report as many problems to the user as we can all in one response. (Unmarshalling errors are usually very low-level syntax errors, so we don't care about those)

Does anyone know if this can be done, or how we might accomplish it?

Comment: You will need to dig into the serialization framework you are using. Has nothing to do with how Jersey works. Just like hibernate-validation has nothing to do with how Jersey works. This is the behavior of hibernate-validation (to collection violations into a set). A serialization framework like Jackson will an exception first problem it seems. I'm not sure how to get around that, if it's even possible. You can sure look into it though. Would be interesting to know if it _is_ possible :-)

Comment: With XML (JAXB) I think it may possible, as you can ignore to fail on errors, then get the list of errors. You can throw an exception your self after collecting the errors. For this though, you will need to write your own MessageBodyReader, that actually handles the unmarshalling.

Comment: In this case, I don't care about failing fast for unmarshalling (which is what Jackson and JaxB primarily do). It's the Data Binding step, where I've unmarshalled into either a cleaner string or an intermediate object and am going to go to a Domain Object that I'm mostly concerned with.

Comment: And in this case, I'm expecting that _I'm_ the serialization framework (most likely)...